# POST image uploading with nginx and jquery/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, nginx

I have my form:

```
<form id="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="#">
    <input id="file" name="file" type="file"/>
    <button type="submit" id="btn">Upload</button>
</form>
```

and my jquery to handle the form and send it off.

```
$('form#upload').live('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    var filename = $("#file").val();

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "http://www.domain.com/upload/", 
            dataType: "html",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: {file: filename},
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var value = responseData;
                alert(value);
            },
            error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('POST failed.');
            }
    });

    return false;

});
```

Now www.domain.com/upload/ is set up with nginx so that it intercepts the upload attempt and processes it -- instead of, for instance, php handling it.

Read more about it: http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2010/08/file-uploading-with-php-and-nginx/

It keeps returning POST failed.  Specifically in my console, I'm seeing either a 400 BAD REQUEST or 405.

Any ideas around this?

Comment: Are uploads working without the Nginx modules but handled by PHP instead? And what do the Nginx logs say about this?

Comment: Standard ajax does not support file uploads. The usual workaround is to use a hidden iframe.

Comment: Hey Marc, how would the logic work with iframes?